# Getting Co-ordinates of inner view corresponding to outer view

Tags: iphone, uiview, coordinate-transformation

My view controller has following hierarchy:

Month view -> Scroll View -> Calendar View -> Grid View -> Container View -> Tile view.

When user clicks the button which is placed in the Tile view, the new view should get added on MonthView -> Scroll View with X-Coordinate same as that of Container View.

I have tried following function :

```
CGRect tranformRect = [Container View convertRect:Container_View_Frame toView:Month view -> Scroll View]
```

But the X-Coordinate which I get is not which I required. Does I m doing any thing wrong? Attached are screen shots :

[image: Initial Image]

[image: Invalid]

[image: Valid]

Thanx in advance.

Comment: Screen shots are attached. 1st is initial one,2nd is Invalid & 3rd is Valid O/P.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are misunderstanding what the frame rect is. The frame for any view is always expressed in its parent's coordinate system.   Try converting containerView.bounds instead.  Or ask gridView to make the conversion instead.

Comment: Thanx. " containerView.bounds " is working. But can you please explain the statement " The frame for any view is always expressed in its parent's coordinate system " with example?

Comment: Let's say you have a small view that is a sub view of a larger view and is positioned the the middle somewhere. The frame of the small view will be like: (100,300,50,50). It's position is measured from the parent view's 0,0. But it's bounds are the same rectangle but measured from its own 0,0. So something like (0,0,50,50)

Comment: So, continuing the statement above, if you ask the the small view to convert (100,300,50,50) to another view, that is a very different rectangle than its frame.  But if you asked the parent to convert that same rectangle it would be the same as the frame.  (the rectangle measurements i have here are entirely arbitrary)  hope that all makes sense.